# Issue with Django rules

Tags: python, django, django-rules

I'm working with rules library from Django and I don't overcome to define rules for specific menu.

Rules library is available there : [rules library](https://pypi.org/project/rules/)

I'm logged as `admin` in my web application.

I have a **menus.py** file like this :

```
class AdminMenuItem(MenuItem):
    def check(self, request):
        return self.allow(request.user)

    @staticmethod
    def allow(user):
        return user.has_perm('app.access_admin_menu')

Menu.add_item('admin', MenuItem('Admin', '#admin', children=settings_children,
                            check=lambda request: AdminMenuItem.allow(request.user)))

settings_children = (
    ...
    AdminMenuItem("Manage Animals", reverse("animal-list-crud"), weight=10),
    AdminMenuItem("Statistics", reverse("statistics"), weight=140)
)
```

Then I defined in my **rules.py** file :

```
from rules.permissions import add_perm
from rules.predicates import predicate


@predicate
def is_admin(user):
    if user.is_anonymous:
        return False
    return True if user.profile.type == 'ED' and user.profile.role == 'AD' else False

# Rules for admin_menu.
add_perm('app.access_admin_menu', is_admin)

# Rules for animal.
add_perm('app.view_animal', is_admin)
add_perm('app.add_animal', is_admin)
add_perm('app.change_animal', is_admin)
add_perm('app.delete_animal', is_admin)
```

It works fine for Animal menu (it's a CRUD part). But when I try to access to the statistics part (which is not a CRUD), I have an error `403 Access forbidden`.

I forgot something in my code ?

Thank you

Comment: `rules` is a 3rd part app, not a django builtin or contrib one. Mentionning this and posting the url to the `django-rules` page would have been better, specially since there are at least 2 packages named "django-rules".

Comment: Which Django version are you using ? Before 1.10, `User.is_anonymous()` is a method, so `bool(user.is_anonymous)` (no parens after `is_anonymous`) will always be true since a method object is true. if you're using anything before 1.10, you have to use `user.is_anonymous()` (with parens)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thank you for your comment. I'm using Django 1.11.18 in my project. So it seems be good isn't it ?

Comment: Yes your code is correct (well, this test at least) for Django 1.11.

Comment: I brought some modifications, but I don't overcome up to now to get access to this part (statistics). It still remains 403 access forbidden. I 'm updating my question (code parts)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The code exposed above is good, but it missed something in my **main.py** code.

```
class StatisticsView(PermissionRequiredMixin, View):
    """ Render the statistics page with a form to generate various stats """

    permission_required = 'app.access_statistics'
    ...
```

In my class, I forgot the attribute `PermissionRequiredMixin` with `permission_required = 'app.access_statistics'`.
By adding both elements, it works now !